# after convert into float data turn into NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

so I tried to convert object into float cvs file but it turns into NaN when I print in python

ive searched in internet and I cant solve it

heres my code
       
`df["tanggal"]= df["tanggal"].str.replace(',','.','-',':','/','').astype(float)`

and heres my data in cvs

```
tanggal,data
1998/04/20 16:02:02.129,0.300199 12.772 2.034
1998/04/20 16:02:03.929,0.43372 10.263 2.743
1998/04/20 16:02:10.930,0.299712 5.97 1.447
1998/04/20 16:02:13.430,0.354663 8.425 2.034
1998/04/20 16:02:19.230,1.945443 2.743 1.34
1998/04/20 16:02:23.131,0.389088 3.445 1.34
1998/04/20 16:02:27.631,0.300199 12.772 2.034
1998/04/20 16:02:29.531,11.467904 12.772 1.447
1998/04/20 16:02:33.531,14.617618 7.04 1.703
1998/04/20 16:02:45.532,10.779831 12.772 1.447
1998/04/20 16:02:52.733,0.229358 12.772 1.447
1998/04/20 16:03:16.335,2.442311 12.772 3.445
1998/04/20 16:03:18.035,8.944965 12.772 1.447
1998/04/20 16:03:21.935,0.229358 12.772 1.447


I expeceted to convert it into float
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert the datetime field to float? What is the expected output of converting '1998/04/20 16:02:02.129'?

Comment: I have converted into datetime pd.to_datetime but when i try to plot with scatter it doesnt work so i think i need to make it into a float

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. Can you include the code for the scatter plot?